# Android widget get touch position

Tags: android, widget, touch, homescreen

is it possible to get the position of a touch when the user touches my widget on the homescreen? TIA

edit: my widget code:

```
public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
public static String ACTION_WIDGET_MEMO = "comNgarsideMemoActionWidgetMemo";
public static String ACTION_WIDGET_PEN = "comNgarsideMemoActionWidgetPen";
public static String ACTION_WIDGET_ERASER = "comNgarsideMemoActionWidgetEraser";
public static String ACTION_WIDGET_UNDO = "comNgarsideMemoActionWidgetUndo";
public static String ACTION_WIDGET_REDO = "comNgarsideMemoActionWidgetRedo";
public static String ACTION_WIDGET_SAVE = "comNgarsideMemoActionWidgetSave";
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
    Intent memoIntent = new Intent(context, ListActivity.class);
    memoIntent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_MEMO);
    Intent penIntent = new Intent(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
    penIntent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_PEN);
    Intent eraserIntent = new Intent(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
    eraserIntent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_ERASER);
    Intent undoIntent = new Intent(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
    undoIntent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_UNDO);
    Intent redoIntent = new Intent(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
    redoIntent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_REDO);
    Intent saveIntent = new Intent(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
    saveIntent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_SAVE);
    PendingIntent memoPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, memoIntent, 0);
    PendingIntent penPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, penIntent, 0);
    PendingIntent eraserPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, eraserIntent, 0);
    PendingIntent undoPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, undoIntent, 0);
    PendingIntent redoPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, redoIntent, 0);
    PendingIntent savePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, saveIntent, 0);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.iconBtn, memoPendingIntent);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.penBtn, penPendingIntent);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.eraserBtn, eraserPendingIntent);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.undoBtn, undoPendingIntent);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.redoBtn, redoPendingIntent);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.saveBtn, savePendingIntent);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final String action = intent.getAction();
    if (AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_DELETED.equals(action)) {
            final int appWidgetId = intent.getExtras().getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        if (appWidgetId != AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
            this.onDeleted(context, new int[] { appWidgetId });
        }
    } else {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_PEN)) {
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_ERASER)) {
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_UNDO)) {
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_REDO)) {
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_SAVE)) {
        }
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this will give you an idea...

**PressureDynamics.java**

```
import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Keyboard sensor
 */
public class PressureDynamics extends Thread implements FeatureExtractor{

    public static final String AVG_TOUCH_PRESSURE = "Avg_Touch_Pressure";

    public static final String AVG_TOUCH_AREA = "Avg_Touch_Area";

    private static final int EVENT_BYTE_SIZE = 16;

    private InputStream _fis = null;

    private boolean _shouldRun;

    private Map<String, TouchScreenSensor> _sensors;

    public PressureDynamics(Context context, Collection<FeatureInfo> featureInfos,
        Long timeStamp){
        super("Pressure Dynamics Feature Extractor Thread");
        _shouldRun = true;

        _sensors = new HashMap<String, TouchScreenSensor>();

        int featureCount = 0;
        for (FeatureInfo featureInfo : featureInfos){
            String name = featureInfo.name;

            try{
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(AVG_TOUCH_PRESSURE)){
                    TouchScreenSensor s = new AvgTouchPressureSensor(featureInfo);
                    _sensors.put(AVG_TOUCH_PRESSURE, s);
                }else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(AVG_TOUCH_AREA)){
                    TouchScreenSensor s = new AvgTouchAreaSensor(featureInfo);
                    _sensors.put(AVG_TOUCH_AREA, s);
                }else{
                    Log.e(FE_TAG, "Unhandled feature by " + getClass().getCanonicalName()
                            + ": " + name);
                    continue;
                }
                ++featureCount;
            }catch(RuntimeException e){
                Log.e(FE_TAG, "Unable to initialize feature: " + name, e);
            }
        }

        if (featureCount == 0){
            throw new FeatureExtractorInitException("No features of "
                    + getClass().getCanonicalName() + " could be initialized");
        }

        _fis = openTouchScreenInputStream();

        start();
    }

    private static InputStream openTouchScreenInputStream(){
        final String HTC_TOUCH_SCREEN_INPUT_FILEPATH = "/dev/input/event1";

        LocalServerConn localServerConn;
        try{
            localServerConn = LocalServerConn.getInstance();
            localServerConn.runLocalServer();
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new FeatureExtractorInitException(
                    "Unable to collect Touch Screen features", e);
        }

        try{
            FileDescriptor[] fdArr = localServerConn
                    .sendFileDescriptorReq(HTC_TOUCH_SCREEN_INPUT_FILEPATH);

            if (fdArr == null || fdArr.length == 0){
                throw new FeatureExtractorInitException("Can't open keyboard device");
            }
            return new FileInputStream(fdArr[0]);
        }catch(IOException e){
            throw new FeatureExtractorInitException("Can't open keyboard input stream: "
                    + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }


    public void close(){
        _shouldRun = false;
    }


    public void collectData(List<MonitoredData> monitoredData, ParcelableDate endTime){
        for (Sensor s : _sensors.values()){
            s.collectData(monitoredData, endTime);
        }
    }


    public void run(){
        int n;
        int pos = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[256];

        for (;;){
            try{
                n = _fis.read(buffer, pos, EVENT_BYTE_SIZE);
                /*
                 * check if we are shutting down - this may have the thread hanging around
                 * until the next touch event comes in
                 */
                if (_shouldRun == false){
                    break;
                }
                pos += n;
                // Log.v(FE_TAG, "read touch screen event: " + n + " bytes\n");
                if (pos >= EVENT_BYTE_SIZE){
                    long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    TouchEvent touchScreenEvent = new TouchEvent(buffer,
                            currentTimeMillis);
                    updateSensors(touchScreenEvent, currentTimeMillis);
                    pos -= EVENT_BYTE_SIZE;
                }
            }catch(IOException e){
                Log.e(FE_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }

    private void updateSensors(TouchEvent touchScreenEvent, long currentTimeMillis){
        try{
            // currently filter out all non preassure event types
            // 
            switch ((int)touchScreenEvent.getCode()){
                case TouchEvent.X_POS_EVENT:
                case TouchEvent.Y_POS_EVENT:
                case TouchEvent.TOUCH_DEVICE_TYPE_EVENT:
                    break;
                case TouchEvent.ABS_PRESSURE_EVENT:
                    _sensors.get(AVG_TOUCH_PRESSURE).updateSensor(touchScreenEvent,
                        currentTimeMillis);
                    break;
                case TouchEvent.ABS_TOOL_WIDTH_EVENT:
                    _sensors.get(AVG_TOUCH_AREA).updateSensor(touchScreenEvent,
                        currentTimeMillis);
                    break;
                default:
                    Log.e(FE_TAG, "unrecognized touch event code :"
                            + touchScreenEvent.getCode());
                    break;
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e(FE_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }


    public String toString(){
        return getClass().getSimpleName();
    }

    private static abstract class TouchScreenSensor extends Sensor{
        private TouchScreenSensor(String name, FeatureInfo info){
            //super(name, info.getValueTimeout());
            super(name);
        }

        public abstract void updateSensor(TouchEvent event, long currentTimeMillis);
    }

    private static class AvgTouchPressureSensor extends TouchScreenSensor{
        public AvgTouchPressureSensor(FeatureInfo info){
            super(AVG_TOUCH_PRESSURE, info);
        }


        public void updateSensor(TouchEvent event, long currentTimeMillis){
            addToAvg(event.getValue(), currentTimeMillis);
        }
    }

    private static class AvgTouchAreaSensor extends TouchScreenSensor{
        public AvgTouchAreaSensor(FeatureInfo info){
            super(AVG_TOUCH_AREA, info);
        }


        public void updateSensor(TouchEvent event, long currentTimeMillis){
            addToAvg(event.getValue(), currentTimeMillis);
        }
    }
}
```

**Sensor.java**

```
import java.util.List;


public class Sensor{
    private final String _name;

    private Double _avg;

    private int _count;

    private long _lastValueUpdateTime;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param name The name of the feature that is collected by this sensor
     * @param valueTimeout The time period of no value changes it takes for the current
     *        value to reset to the initial value (in millis)
     */
    public Sensor(String name){
        _lastValueUpdateTime = 0;
        _name = name;
        _avg = null;
        _count = 0;
    }

    public void collectData(List<MonitoredData> monitoredData, ParcelableDate endTime){
        Double value = getValue(endTime.getTime());

        if (value != null){
            value = Utils.truncateDouble(value);
        }

        monitoredData.add(new MonitoredData(_name, value, endTime));
    }

    public Double getValue(long time){
        if (time - _lastValueUpdateTime > MainActivity.getAgentLoopTime()){
            _avg = null;
            _count = 0;
        }

        return _avg;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return _name;
    }

    public void addToAvg(double value, long time){      
        Double avg = getValue(time);

        if (avg == null){
            avg = value; // Initial value
        }else{
            value = (avg * _count + value) / (_count + 1);
        }   
        ++_count;

        _avg = value;
        _lastValueUpdateTime = time;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return _name;
    }
}
```

**TouchEvent.java**

```
import android.util.Log;
import dt.util.Utils;

    public class TouchEvent{

        public static final int ABS_PRESSURE_EVENT = 0x18;

        public static final int ABS_TOOL_WIDTH_EVENT = 0x1c;

        public static final int X_POS_EVENT = 0x0;

        public static final int Y_POS_EVENT = 0x1;

        /* type of touching device ie. finger, stylus etc. */
        public static final int TOUCH_DEVICE_TYPE_EVENT = 0x14a;

        // private final long _timeStamp;

        // private final int _sec;

        // private final int _usec;

        // 3, 1, 0 - ?
        // private final long _type;

        // different event types have different codes
        private final long _code;

        private final int _value;

        // 
        public TouchEvent(byte[] _buffer, long currentTimeMillis){
            int pos;
            byte b[] = new byte[4];
            byte s[] = new byte[2];

            // _timeStamp = currentTimeMillis;

            pos = 0;
            // _sec = Utils.LittleEndianBytesToInt(_buffer);
            pos += 4;
            System.arraycopy(_buffer, pos, b, 0, 4);
            // _usec = Utils.LittleEndianBytesToInt(b);
            pos += 4;
            // _type = Utils.LittleEndianBytesToUShort(s);
            pos += 2;
            System.arraycopy(_buffer, pos, s, 0, 2);
            _code = Utils.littleEndianBytesToUShort(s);
            pos += 2;
            System.arraycopy(_buffer, pos, b, 0, 4);
            _value = Utils.littleEndianBytesToInt(b);

            if (_code != X_POS_EVENT && _code != Y_POS_EVENT
                    && _code != TOUCH_DEVICE_TYPE_EVENT && _code != ABS_PRESSURE_EVENT
                    && _code != ABS_TOOL_WIDTH_EVENT){
                Log.d(FE_TAG, "unrecognized touch event code :" + _code);
            }
        }

        public long getCode(){
            return _code;
        }

        public double getValue(){
            return _value;
        }
    }
```

**FeatureInfo.java**

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class FeatureInfo{
    /** The name of the feature */
    public final String name;

    /** The parameters relevant to the feature */
    public final HashMap<String, String> params;

    /**
     * Constructs a FeatureInfo object from the given parameters
     * 
     * @param name The name of the feature
     * @param params The parameters relevant to the feature
     */
    public FeatureInfo(String name, HashMap<String, String> params){
        this.name = name;
        this.params = (params == null) ? new HashMap<String, String>() : params;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return name;
    }

    public int getTimeWindow() throws IllegalArgumentException{
        final String paramName = "Time_Window";
        try{
            int timeWindow = Integer.parseInt(params.get(paramName)) * 1000;
            if (timeWindow <= 0){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must be a positive integer");
            }
            return timeWindow;
        }catch(Exception e){// NullPointer or Parsing
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Corrupt parameter: " + paramName
                    + " in feature " + name, e);
        }
    }

//  public int getTimeWindow() throws IllegalArgumentException{
//      final String paramName = "Time_Window";
//      try{
//          int timeWindow = Integer.parseInt(params.get(paramName)) * 1000;
//          if (timeWindow <= 0){
//              throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must be a positive integer");
//          }
//          return timeWindow;
//      }catch(Exception e){// NullPointer or Parsing
//          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Corrupt parameter: " + paramName
//                  + " in feature " + name, e);
//      }
//  }

    public int getValueTimeout() throws IllegalArgumentException{
        final String paramName = "Value_Timeout";
        try{
            int valueTimeout = Integer.parseInt(params.get(paramName)) * 1000;
            if (valueTimeout <= 0){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must be a positive integer");
            }
            return valueTimeout;
        }catch(Exception e){// NullPointer or Parsing
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Corrupt parameter: " + paramName
                    + " in feature " + name, e);
        }
    }

    public double getMovieAverageWeight() throws IllegalArgumentException{
        final String paramName = "Moving_Average_Weight";
        try{
            double movingAverageWeight = Double.parseDouble(params.get(paramName));
            if (movingAverageWeight < 0 || movingAverageWeight > 1){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must be positive and 1.0 at most");
            }
            return movingAverageWeight;
        }catch(Exception e){// NullPointer or Parsing
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Corrupt parameter: " + paramName
                    + " in feature " + name, e);
        }
    }

    public boolean getIncludeEventTimes(){
        final String paramName = "Include_Event_Times";
        return Boolean.parseBoolean(params
            .get(paramName));
    }

    public boolean getIncludeMaximalEntity(){
        final String paramName = "Include_Maximal_Entity";
        return Boolean.parseBoolean(params
            .get(paramName));
    }
}
```

**MonitoredData.java**

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class MonitoredData implements Map, Parcelable{
    public static final int DEFAULT = 0;

    public static final int HAS_EXTRAS = 1;

    protected String _name;

    protected ParcelableDate _startTime, _endTime;

    protected Object _value;

    protected Bundle _extras;

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<MonitoredData> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<MonitoredData>(){
        public MonitoredData createFromParcel(Parcel in){
            ClassLoader cl = ParcelableDate.class.getClassLoader();
            String name = in.readString();
            Object value = in.readValue(null);
            ParcelableDate startTime = (ParcelableDate)in.readParcelable(cl);
            ParcelableDate endTime = (ParcelableDate)in.readParcelable(cl);
            Bundle extras = in.readBundle();
            MonitoredData monitoredData = new MonitoredData(name, value, startTime,
                    endTime);
            if (extras != null){
                monitoredData.setExtras(extras);
            }
            return monitoredData;
        }

        public MonitoredData[] newArray(int size){
            return new MonitoredData[size];
        }
    };

    private static DateFormat _sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");

    public MonitoredData(String name, Object value, Date endTime){
        this(name, value, new ParcelableDate(endTime), new ParcelableDate(endTime));
    }

    public MonitoredData(String name, Object value, ParcelableDate endTime){
        this(name, value, endTime, endTime);
    }

    public MonitoredData(String name, Object value, Date startTime, Date endTime){
        this(name, value, new ParcelableDate(startTime), new ParcelableDate(endTime));
    }

    public MonitoredData(String name, Object value, Date startTime, ParcelableDate endTime){
        this(name, value, new ParcelableDate(startTime), endTime);
    }

    public MonitoredData(String name, Object value, ParcelableDate startTime,
        ParcelableDate endTime){
        _name = name;
        _startTime = startTime;
        _endTime = endTime;
        _value = value;
        _extras = null;
    }

    public void setExtras(Bundle extras){
        _extras = extras;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> toMap(){
        TreeMap<String, Object> map = new TreeMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("Name", _name);
        map.put("StartTime", _startTime);
        map.put("EndTime", _endTime);
        map.put("Value", _value);
        return map;
    }

    public String conciseToString(){
        String extrasToString = (_extras != null && !_extras.isEmpty()) ? " - "
                + _extras.toString() : "";
        return "{" + getName() + " = " + getValue() + "}" + extrasToString;
    }


    public int describeContents(){
        return (_extras == null || _extras.isEmpty()) ? DEFAULT : HAS_EXTRAS;
    }

    public ParcelableDate getEndTime(){
        return _endTime;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return _name;
    }

    public ParcelableDate getStartTime(){
        return _startTime;
    }

    public Object getValue(){
        return _value;
    }

    public Bundle getExtras(){
        return _extras;
    }


    public String toString(){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("{");
        sb.append("Name = " + getName() + ", ");
        sb.append("Value = " + getValue() + ", ");
        sb.append("StartTime = " + _sdf.format(getStartTime()) + ", ");
        sb.append("EndTime = " + _sdf.format(getEndTime()));
        sb.append("}");
        return sb.toString();
    }


    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags){
        dest.writeString(getName());
        dest.writeValue(getValue());
        dest.writeParcelable(getStartTime(), 0);
        dest.writeParcelable(getEndTime(), 0);
        dest.writeBundle(_extras);
    }


    public void clear(){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }


    public boolean containsKey(Object key){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }


    public boolean containsValue(Object value){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }


    public Set entrySet(){
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(toMap().entrySet());
    }


    public Object get(Object key){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }


    public boolean isEmpty(){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }


    public Set keySet(){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }


    public Object put(Object key, Object value){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }


    public void putAll(Map arg0){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }


    public Object remove(Object key){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }


    public int size(){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }


    public Collection values(){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the value of the monitored data as a Double. 
     * Null is returned if the value is null or is can not be converted to double.
     * 
     * @return The value as double if possible, null otherwise
     */
    public Double mdToDouble(){
        Double sample;
        Object val = getValue();
        if (val instanceof Double){
            sample = ((Double)val).doubleValue();
        }else if (val instanceof Long){
            sample = ((Long)val).doubleValue();
        }else if (val instanceof Integer){
            sample = ((Integer)val).doubleValue();
        }else{
            sample = null;
        }
        return sample;
    }
}
```

**Utils.java**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.List;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Utils{
    public static byte[] append(byte[] first, byte[] second){
        byte[] bytes;

        bytes = new byte[first.length + second.length];
        System.arraycopy(first, 0, bytes, 0, first.length);
        System.arraycopy(second, 0, bytes, first.length, second.length);

        return bytes;
    }

    public static int bytesToInt(byte[] bytes){
        return (bytes[3] & 0xFF) | ((bytes[2] & 0xFF) << 8) | ((bytes[1] & 0xFF) << 16)
                | ((bytes[0] & 0xFF) << 24);
    }

    public static int littleEndianBytesToInt(byte[] bytes){
        return (bytes[0] & 0xFF) | ((bytes[1] & 0xFF) << 8) | ((bytes[2] & 0xFF) << 16)
                | ((bytes[3] & 0xFF) << 24);
    }

    public static long littleEndianBytesToUShort(byte[] arr){
        return (arr[1] << 8) | arr[0];
    }

    public static void displayShortAlert(Context context, String message){
        Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public static XmlPullParser getXPP(Context context, int resourceId, boolean isBinary){
        XmlPullParser xpp;
        Resources resources = context.getResources();

        if (isBinary){
            return resources.getXml(resourceId);
        }else{
            try{
                XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                xpp = factory.newPullParser();
                xpp.setInput(resources.openRawResource(resourceId), null);
            }catch(XmlPullParserException e){
                xpp = null;
            }
            return xpp;
        }
    }

    public static byte[] intToBytes(int i){
        byte[] bytes = new byte[]{(byte)((i >> 24) & 0xff), (byte)((i >> 16) & 0xff),
                (byte)((i >> 8) & 0xff), (byte)((i) & 0xff)};
        return bytes;
    }

    /*
     * debugging
     */
    public static String printByteArray(byte[] bytes, int len){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("msg len: " + len + " :");
        Formatter f = new Formatter(sb);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
            f.format("%2x", bytes[i]);
        }
        sb.append("\n");
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static List<Integer> getPids(String fileName){
        String line;
        int pidIndex = -1;

        try{
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps " + fileName);
            p.waitFor();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()), 256);
            if ((line = br.readLine()) == null){
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to read ps output");
            }
            String[] tokens = line.split(" +");
            for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; ++i){
                if (tokens[i].equalsIgnoreCase("pid")){
                    pidIndex = i;
                }
            }
            if (pidIndex < 0){
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to locate pid field in ps output");
            }

            List<Integer> pids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                tokens = line.split(" +");
                assert tokens.length < 9;

                try{
                    pids.add(Integer.parseInt(tokens[pidIndex]));
                }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Pid is not an integer");
                }
            }

            br.close();
            return pids;
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to read running process through ps: "
                    + e.getMessage(), e);
        }

    }

    public static void killProcesses(List<Integer> pids){
        for (Integer pid : pids){
            android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
        }
    }

    public static void killProcesses(String processName){
        killProcesses(getPids(processName));
    }

    public static void suKillProcesses(List<Integer> pids){
        StringBuilder cmd = new StringBuilder("kill");
        for (Integer pid : pids){
            cmd.append(" ").append(pid);
        }
        try{
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", cmd.toString()});
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void suKillProcess(int pid){
        try{
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "kill " + pid});
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void suKillProcesses(String processName){
        suKillProcesses(getPids(processName));
    }

    public static double truncateDouble(double d){
        long l = Math.round(d * 100);
        return l / 100.0;
    }

    public static double calcMovingAvg(double oldVal, double newVal, double newValWeight){
        return (oldVal * (1.0 - newValWeight)) + (newValWeight * newVal);
    }

    public static double calcAvg(double oldAvg, int count, double newVal){
        return (oldAvg * count + newVal) / (count + 1);
    }

    public static void writeLogToFile(Context context, boolean onSdcard, String prefix, int timeWindowInSeconds) throws Exception{
        final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH-mm-ss");
        final DateFormat logDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        final long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final long startTime = currentTime - timeWindowInSeconds * 1000;
        final String currentYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-";
        final String logFileName = prefix + sdf.format(new Date(currentTime)) + ".log";
        BufferedReader logcatIn;
        Process logcat;
        OutputStream logFile;

        try{
            logcat = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -v time -d *:d");
            logcatIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(logcat
                    .getInputStream()), 1024);
        }catch(IOException e){
            throw new Exception("Unable to launch logcat: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        try{
            if (onSdcard){
                logFile = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), logFileName));
            }else{
                logFile = context.openFileOutput(logFileName, 0);               
            }
        }catch(IOException e){
            throw new Exception("Unable to create log file: " + e.getMessage(), e);         
        }
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(logFile, false);

        String line;
        long logLineTime;
        while ((line = logcatIn.readLine()) != null){
            logLineTime = logDF.parse(currentYear + line.substring(0, line.indexOf(".") + 4)).getTime();
            if (logLineTime >= startTime){
                pw.println(line);
            }
        }

        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
        logcatIn.close();
        logcat.destroy();
    }
}
```

**FeatureExtractor.java**

```
import java.util.List;

/**
 * A class capable of extracting one or more features. It MUST have a public constructor
 * with the following parameters in this order:
 * <ul>
 * <li>Context context</li>
 * <li>Collection&lt;FeatureInfo&gt; featureInfos</li>
 * <li>Long timeStamp</li>
 * </ul>
 * 
 */
public interface FeatureExtractor{
    /**
     * Invoked during a data collection. It is up to the extractor to add the data
     * relevant to it's monitored features to the monitoredData list.
     * 
     * @param monitoredData The overall collected data (from all extractors) so far
     * @param endTime The time of the current data collection
     */
    public void collectData(List<MonitoredData> monitoredData, ParcelableDate endTime);

    /**
     * Invoked when the feature extractor is no longer needed. This is the place to
     * release any resources, unregister any listeners, close any threads, etc.
     */
    public void close();
}
```

**FeatureExtractorInitException.java**

```
public class FeatureExtractorInitException extends RuntimeException{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public FeatureExtractorInitException(String message){
        super(message);
    }

    public FeatureExtractorInitException(String message, Throwable t){
        super(message, t);
    }

    public FeatureExtractorInitException(Throwable t){
        super(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however i'm very much a noob with widgets so have no idea how to implement that? How should i do it? Thanks

Comment: Create a package within your project. Paste all of the files with appropriate names there and then let me know what is missing, what errors and bugs you have.

Comment: I've added the files to my project. FeatureInfo is fine. MonitoredData had errors because it couldn't find ParcelableDate, but I found/downloaded a ParcelableDate file from google and now it seems to be fine. TouchEvent can't find Utils.littleEndianBytesToInt(byte[]), and I don't know enough about working with bytes to fix it. Sensor can't find Utils.truncateDouble(double) and I wasn't sure how many digits to truncate it to so have left it.

Comment: Sensor is also trying and failing to call MainActivity.getAgentLoopTime(). I'm not sure what to do with this as my app has three activitys but I can't guarantee they'll be open when the widget is being used. PressureDynamics is using FeatureExtractor a lot but I can't find a FeatureExtractor class. It's also using LocalServerConn but again I can't find a LocalServerConn class. Other than that there were some missing TAG strings for the Log statements but I fixed that, and theres a few warnings but doubt they'll affect anything? Cheers for the help BTW.

Comment: I've edited that post and added Utils.java class. Insert that one too. Remove MainActivity.getAgentLoopTime(), that has to do with my app. No problem for the help I hope it helps you. Feel free to upvote my post if it is of any use to you :).

Comment: Also browse through these: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html , http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/package-summary.html , http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onTouchEvent

Comment: Done that now the only problem is PressureDynamics.java can't find FeatureExtractor, FeatureExtractorInitException or LocalServerConn.

Comment: I added a FeatureExtractor.java as well to that post, that is just an interface.

Comment: PressureDynamics can't find LocalServerConn or FeatureExtractorInitException, is it ok to remove these?

Comment: Yea, you can remove those, they are not relevant in your case.

Comment: Actually, you can leave FeatureExtractorInitException, I uploaded that file as well.

Comment: I've commented out openTouchScreenInputStream() in PressureDynamics.java and added FeatureExtractorInitException.java and still got a few warnings but no errors.

Answer (score 0):

For example if you had an imageView one way of fetching coordinates is...

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int[] values = new int[2]; 
            view.getLocationOnScreen(values);
            Log.d("X & Y",values[0]+" "+values[1]);
        }
    });
```

Check out these ST threads:

- [How to get imageView inside onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10251002/how-to-get-imageview-inside-ontoucheventmotionevent-event-in-android)
- [Android: How do I get the x y coordinates within an image / ImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909835/android-how-do-i-get-the-x-y-coordinates-within-an-image-imageview)
- [OnClickListener - x,y location of event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967039/onclicklistener-x-y-location-of-event)
- [Find layout with x,y coordinate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329993/find-layout-with-x-y-coordinate)

Comment: Would this work in a widget? Sorry if this seems stupid lol but all the code i've seen for working with views in widgets uses RemoteViews, and i'm not sure how to use this code with RemoteViews? Thanks

Comment: No question is stupid, it is stupid not to ask. Ask freely. To my knowledge only clicks are available, other gestures are not.

Comment: I've edited my OP with the widget code, would you be able to show how to implement this code in it? Thanks a ton

Comment: From what I see you should have a class that will extend AppWidgetHostView: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetHostView.html - from there you have a method getDefaultView() which returns Widgets view, so your onClick should look like - (View myWidgetHostView.getDefaultView()) ... Thats all I have now, have not worked a lot with widgets. If i have time, I will look at it tomorrow again.

Comment: Also take a look at code repositories under Github and Google code in this post I made fro Android resources - http://stackoverflow.com/a/10899469/824009 , there must be an example for Widgets...A lot of really useful code can be found there. Upvote the post if you like it.

Comment: Ok i'm reading through the links but tbh most of the stuff is going way over my head :o. Also how does this interact with the code in your other answer? TIA

Comment: @reuf It is interesting if your answer be correct.I saw many answers in about this topic that say `YOU CAN NOT DETECT TOUCH ON APPWIDGET`. Do you can add more details in about your idea?Your codes are numerous.I want to understand your main idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you use reuf codes,you will need to use `ParcelableData.java`.I add ParcelableData class that found [here](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/Client/moloko/dev/drsoran/moloko/service/parcel/ParcelableDate.java.htm) and hope to save your time:

```
package dev.drsoran.moloko.service.parcel;

import java.util.Date;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;


public class ParcelableDate implements Parcelable
{

   public static final Parcelable.Creator< ParcelableDate > CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator< ParcelableDate >()
   {

      public ParcelableDate createFromParcel( Parcel source )
      {
         return new ParcelableDate( source );
      }



      public ParcelableDate[] newArray( int size )
      {
         return new ParcelableDate[ size ];
      }

   };

   private final Date date;



   public ParcelableDate( final Date date )
   {
      this.date = date;
   }



   public ParcelableDate( long millis )
   {
      this.date = new Date( millis );
   }



   public ParcelableDate( Parcel source )
   {
      date = new Date( source.readLong() );
   }



   public Date getDate()
   {
      return date;
   }



   @Override
   public String toString()
   {
      return date.toString();
   }



   public int describeContents()
   {
      return 0;
   }



   public void writeToParcel( Parcel dest, int flags )
   {
      dest.writeLong( date.getTime() );
   }

}
```