# Android Widget Touch Position

Tags: android, android-widget, widget, position, touch

Hi, at the moment I'm trying to develop a widget with a background image. If I touch somewhere in that widget I'd like to get the position of that touch. I know there is a solution or maybe rather a workaround...

[Android widget get touch position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10936040/android-widget-get-touch-position/12659657#12659657)

... but apart from the fact, that it seems to be quite extensive I don't think that it would be a solution to my problem. I only want the touch event IN my widget and not from the whole screen around.

I've already tried some approaches like getting a view from the RemoteView, but of course I couldnt... The interesting thing is, that you can add Views, but not receive any from `RemoteView`. Or is there a possibility? Because then you could maybe add an `ontouchListener`?

Thanks in advance

Greetings, Timo

Comment: Have you found a solution for that?